# MySql syntax serror

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have error syntax error in  the following stored procedure :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_IncDecReferenceCount`;
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_IncDecReferenceCount`(pReferenceID int)
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT * from filesrefrences where filesrefrences.ReferenceID= pReferenceID and filesrefrences.RefrenceCount>1) then 
update filesrefrences
set 
    filesrefrences.RefrenceCount= filesrefrences.RefrenceCount-1
where 
        filesrefrences.ReferenceID= pReferenceID;
SELECT pReferenceID;
ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * from filesrefrences where filesrefrences.ReferenceID= pReferenceID) then 
DELETE from filesrefrences WHERE filesrefrences.ReferenceID = pReferenceID;
SELECT -77;
ELSE
SELECT -99;
end if ;
END;
```

the error is : 
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8

Comment: I removed the **DEFINER = `root`@`localhost`** , then the problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the `DELIMITER`. eg,

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_IncDecReferenceCount`;

DELIMITER &&

CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_IncDecReferenceCount`(pReferenceID int)
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * from filesrefrences where filesrefrences.ReferenceID= pReferenceID and filesrefrences.RefrenceCount>1) then 
        update filesrefrences
        set 
            filesrefrences.RefrenceCount= filesrefrences.RefrenceCount-1
        where 
                filesrefrences.ReferenceID= pReferenceID;
        SELECT pReferenceID;
    ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * from filesrefrences where filesrefrences.ReferenceID= pReferenceID) then 
        DELETE from filesrefrences WHERE filesrefrences.ReferenceID = pReferenceID;
        SELECT -77;
    ELSE
        SELECT -99;
    end if ;
END &&

DELIMITER ;
```